# How to enable iOS capabilities from xarchive?

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

So when providing a build to a client we archive it with our key and provisioning profile and they then resign it again with their key. But then how do we enable iOS Push Notifications Capabilities as we can't create the archive for the bundle ID with our keys after enabling the capability.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you exactly mean by saying '...as we can't create the archive for the bundle ID with our keys after enabling the capability.'?

Comment: @Lasse as the bundle ID isn't registered in our account, we can't make a build with the push notification capability on. We can create development builds using our certificate but the client's bundle ID if notification isn't turned on.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you're out of luck. When you use entitlements in your app you have to use the proper Bundle-Id, Certificate and Provisioning Profile when archiving. We had the same problem and the only solution was to use proper Development Signing.

By that I mean:

1. Ask your client to give you access to his Developer Portal. They only need to give you the 'Member' Role. With that you can create your own Development Certificate, and you can download existing Provisioning Profiles, but you can't do much more than that.
2. Create your own Development Certificate.
3. Ask your client to generate a Development Provisioning Profile for the app in question and have your Development Certificate included. This Provisioning Profile also needs to include the Push Notification Capability.
4. Install the Certificate and the Provisioning Profile on your machine or CI server and set up the Xcode Project to use these for signing.
5. Don't forget to use the final Bundle-Id now.
6. Archive your app. You'll get a development-signed Xcarchive which includes all Entitlements / Capabilities.

Now you can transfer this Xcarchive to your client. They will need to re-sign it with their Distribution Certificate and Provisioning Profile and can then upload to the AppStore.